# Race Condition When SELECT And Insert Data Concurrently

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a simple program and have DB containing table A. I want to get data by a non-unique index from table A and if the data is null then I'll insert data to table A. If this program runs concurrently, can this program cause a race condition where the same data is inserted twice?

Here is the sample program, I'm using Spring JPA.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class TestRaceConditionServiceImpl implements TestRaceConditionService {
    private final TestRepository testRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Boolean raceConditions(){
        //name is not unique index
        Test test = testRepository.findByName("john");
        
        if(Objects.isNull(test)){
            test = new Test();
            test.setName("john");
            testRepository.save(test);
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

If there  is two or more concurrent process run  this  program, is there a possibility that the data with name "john" inserted twice?

Comment: Please provide sample data

Comment: How many threads would be doing the reads and writes?

Comment: If you want to ensure uniqueness, the only way is to define a unique constraint.

Comment: That probably depends on what your transaction isolation level is.  But this seems at least as much a JPA question as a PostgreSQL one.